# Where If-Match header comes from?

Tags: java, html, video

I have progressive download streaming in my Java application and I am using popular MultipartFileSender by Kevin to serve the video: https://gist.github.com/davinkevin/b97e39d7ce89198774b4#file-multipartfilesender on the back-end and video.js on the front-end.

In this file sender there is code where If-Match header is checked and if it doesn't match ETag (filename) the error is sent in the response.

```
String ifMatch = request.getHeader("If-Match");
if (ifMatch != null && !HttpUtils.matches(ifMatch, fileName)) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED);
    return;
}
```

Here is my problem:
Let say I uploaded file into the system and opened the page with HTML5 video playback - everything is good here, video playback works. Then, I have replaced video file with another one - the file is stored with different unique file name (internal logic). After this, when I open video page again the new video file is retrieved on the back-end with new file name, however browser still sends If-Match header with old file name, so mismatch appears: new_file_name != If-Match header's value.

I wasn't able to figure out why browser sends deprecated value in If-Match header. Could you please point me out where If-Match header comes from? I didn't find any info regarding video.js sending it or regarding adding this by tomcat server.